# Unable to Use ResultReuseConfiguration in Athena Client

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I'm trying to apply query result reuse in AWS Athena using the javascript sdk, but I'm getting this error in CloudWatch: `UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'ResultReuseConfiguration' found in params`

Here is my code:

```
            const params = {
              QueryString: `SELECT * FROM "some_database"."some_table"`,
              ResultConfiguration: {
                OutputLocation:
                  "someurl",
              },
              ResultReuseConfiguration: {
                ResultReuseByAgeConfiguration: {
                  Enabled: true,
                  MaxAgeInMinutes: 10800,
                },
              },
            };

            athena.startQueryExecution(params, function (err, data) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
              } else {
                console.log(data);
                const queryExecutionId = data.QueryExecutionId;
              ...
```

which mirrors what the documentation says is the request syntax: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_StartQueryExecution.html

```
{
   "ClientRequestToken": "string",
   "ExecutionParameters": [ "string" ],
   "QueryExecutionContext": { 
      "Catalog": "string",
      "Database": "string"
   },
   "QueryString": "string",
   "ResultConfiguration": { 
      "AclConfiguration": { 
         "S3AclOption": "string"
      },
      "EncryptionConfiguration": { 
         "EncryptionOption": "string",
         "KmsKey": "string"
      },
      "ExpectedBucketOwner": "string",
      "OutputLocation": "string"
   },
   "ResultReuseConfiguration": { 
      "ResultReuseByAgeConfiguration": { 
         "Enabled": boolean,
         "MaxAgeInMinutes": number
      }
   },
   "WorkGroup": "string"
}
```

My @aws-sdk/client-athena is at version 3.264.0, which means `ResultReuseConfiguration` should be supported.

Why would I be getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same issue before adding `ResultReuseConfiguration`.

I initially had it like:

```js
 ResultReuseConfiguration: {
      Enabled: true,
      MaxAgeInMinutes: 60,
  },
```

I updated the parameters according to the documentation and it is now working. This is what the whole object looks like:

```js
{
    QueryString: query,
    ResultConfiguration: {
      OutputLocation: config.s3_output_location,
    },
    QueryExecutionContext: {
      Database: config.database,
    },
    ResultReuseConfiguration: {
      ResultReuseByAgeConfiguration: {
        Enabled: true,
        MaxAgeInMinutes: 60,
      },
    },
  }
```

I am on aws-sdk version 2.1348.0 for what it's worth.

Comment: my issue was I was on the wrong sdk version that didn't support this configuration. this was helpful